# Update view model inside .done() callback of $.post method call, is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm starting to use KnockoutJS and of course doubts comes to me. So I have this jQuery code:

```
$.post("someUrl", $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.cookie("stepOneSave", true);

    // here I should update the attributes from response in data
}).fail(function () {
    return false;
}).always();
```

And then in my view (it's a Twig template since this is part of Symfony2 project) I have this:

```
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
    <legend class="rpni-border">Datos de Solicitud</legend>
    <div class="spacer10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><strong>Number:</strong></p>
        <p><strong data-bind="text: currIDSolicitud"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Request Type: </p>
        <p><strong data-bind="text: currTipoSolicitud"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Office: </p>
        <p><strong data-bind="text: currOficinaRegional"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Status: </p>
        <p><strong data-bind="text: currEstadoSolicitud"></strong></p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Using the info provided how do I update  the attributes and bind them to the view? This is my first time with Knockout and I start reading [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) but it's not clear to me this, can any give me some help?

Comment: Still doesn't clear what do you need, can you try to explain a bit more or show some more code ?

Comment: @FarizAzmi I need to update model attributes when `.done()` callback is executed and bind the values to the view and no more code, is my first time and I don't know where to put it and how, still reading right now but need some push or sample code to start from there

Comment: My advice is to take your time and go over the tutorial step by step again.  Make sure you fully understand what's being explained at each step.  And the first time you don't understand something, go to jsfiddle.net, copy the tutorial code there and play with it.  Then you can post a question here with some working code and your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let say you have this data returned from server using ajax request

```
data: [
  {
     id: 1,
     name: 'John',
     age: 17
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     name: 'Doe',
     age: 20
  }
];
```

inside a viewmodel function you need to define one property as a observableArray to handle above data:

```
var viewModel = function()
{
   var self = this;

   self.friends = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

now from code above you already have empty `friends` observableArray, next you need to write your ajax request to fetch data from server then insert it to observableArray:

```
var ViewModel = function()
{
   var self = this;

   self.friends = ko.observableArray([]);
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
   var viewmodel = new ViewModel();

   ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());

   $.ajax({
      url: '/example',

      // more ajax options...

      success: function(response)
      {
         viewmodel.friends(response.data);
      }
   });
});
```

and here is the view will look alike:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.friends">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="text: name"></div>
       <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="text: age"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, if you want to add `class` attribute, do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.friends">
    <div class="row" data-bind="css: age < 18 ? 'kid' : 'adult'">
       <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="text: name"></div>
       <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="text: age"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or maybe you want to add `href` attribute, do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.friends">
    <div class="row" data-bind="css: age < 18 ? 'kid' : 'adult'">
       <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="text: name"></div>
       <a data-bind="text: age, attr: { href: age < 18 ? 'http://kid.com' : 'http://adult.com' }"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Read more about `attr binding` [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

p/s: This is not a good approach, but it should be working !